# OSX: Why is my launchd agent running my script twice?

Tags: macos, bash, launchd, launch-daemon, launchdagent

I have one plist associated with this launchd agent. There is one agent listed in `launchctl list`, and it calls my bash script, called rc.wakeup, whenever the mac is woken up from sleep. There is only one copy of this bash script. The code in the bash script is not repeated. Despite this, the bash script is being executed twice in its entirety. Why?

EDIT: I have created an install bash script and an uninstall bash script. I have been executing these in series an an attempt to get both scripts working so this program can be used by anyone. I believe improperly installing/uninstalling these files has caused the problem, although I have no idea why it would.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.  Try http://apple.stackexchange.com.  Also you'll need to provide more information than this.

Comment: thanks for that. i'l do that.